# Why potassium carbonate breaks glass when heated?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, heat, equipment

I have been studying about desiccants for a while and testing some inorganic salts, including calcium chloride, sodium sulfate and potassium carbonate. When they get enough moisture from air, I dehydrate them by heating up in a borosilicate glass, and during the process everything looks fine for all, but with potassium carbonate the glass always breaks after 1 or 2 cycles, and I don't know why. It should be clear that this doesn't happen with the other salts even after more than 15 cycles so far, and it takes several minutes or even hours after the glass cools down (I didn't even watch the exact moment when this happens). I'm using an electric heater in a low setting temperature, taking about 15 minutes to reach the final temperature about 250 to 280 °C. I will be grateful for your answer and any suggestions of what material could be more appropriate for the task

Comment: How fast, in what way and to what T do you heat them? The best if you describe the whole procedure in details, otherwise the question itself may become yet another layer of the puzzle. // If hot enough, the carbonate may chemically damage the glass structure, potassium oxide getting incorporated in the borosilicate. Remember alkaline carbonates were used for ages to make glass. You may try rather iron based metallic vessel for it.

Comment: I am using an electric heater, it takes about 15 minutes to reach the set temperature of approximately 250 °C, and it doesn't break while heating up, but after cooling at least 20 minutes later

Answer (score 1):

If the beakers are not made of borosilicate glass, it will react with the metal carbonate and break the glassware:

> Fusion with an alkali metal carbonate, usually anhydrous sodium or potassium carbonate or their mixture, decomposes glass samples very effectively. This occurs above the melting point of the carbonate(s): $\ce{Na2CO3}$, 853°C; $\ce{K2CO3}$, 903°C; $\ce{KNaCO3}$, 712°C. If it is known that the glass does not contain boron, the fusion sample is fused with a mixture of sodium carbonate and borax to decrease the fusion temperature. The complex silicate network is broken down, and monosilicates are formed. Other anions present are released, and network modifiers form salts corresponding to the acid used finally to dissolve the cold fusion mixture. This reaction is accompanied by evolution of carbon dioxide.

**Source**: M.P. Syomov, O.V. Rakhimova, in Encyclopedia of Analytical Science (Second Edition), **2005**

Comment: And even if it *is* borosilicate glass, it contains silica and will still react as you describe, though possibly more slowly.

Comment: But I am not reaching that high temperatures, the maximum I am using is 280 °C in the base of the hotplate of the electric heater